# Finding rational points via birational map

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, rational-points

Let $C$ be an affine curve given by $p_C(x,y)=0$ where $$ p_C=2x^3y + 2xy^3 +x^3 + y^3 + 5x^2y + 5xy^2 + 2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2x^2y^2 + 2xy $$
and let $\overline{C}$ denote the projective closure of $C$. For  $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-33})$, I am trying to determine all $K$-rational points on $\overline{C}$.
Sage/Magma tells us that $\overline{C}$ has genus 1 and is birational (over $\mathbb{Q}$) to the elliptic curve $E_C$ defined by the equation
$$ y^2+2xy+2y = x^3 - x^2 - 2x$$
with the map $\phi$ given by
$$ \phi : \overline{C} \rightarrow E_C $$
$$    (x,y,z) \mapsto (p_1^{\phi}, p_2^{\phi},p_3^{\phi} ) $$
where
$$ p_1^{\phi}=2x^2y^2 + 3x^2yz + 4xy^2z + x^2z^2 + x^2z^2 + 6xyz^2 -y^2z^2 + 2xz^3 $$
$$ p_2^{\phi} = 2x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 - x2^yz + 10xy2^z + 3y^3z - x^2z2^ + 7y2^z2 - 2xz^3 + 2yz^3 $$
$$ p_3^{\phi} = y^4 + 3y^3z + 3y^2z^2 + yz^3$$
By Sage the Mordell-Weil rank is positive and more precisely $E(K) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}.$ (In fact, $E_C$ is birational to the modular curve $X_0(36)$ with equation $y^2=x^3+1)$. Does this imply that there are infinitely many $K$-rational points on $\overline{C}$ under $\phi$?

Comment: Is the pseudo-inverse of $\phi$ defined over $K$ ?

Comment: Note that any birational morphism between smooth projective curves uniquely extends to an isomorphism, so if $\bar{C}$ is smooth and $\phi$ is well-defined then the rational points on $E_C$ should correspond exactly to those of $\bar{C}$ under $\phi$

Comment: I guess $C$ has a singularity at the origin, so it fails to be smooth. But in any case $\bar{C}$ will only differ from $E_C$ at finitely many points so $\bar{C}$ certainly still has infinitely many $K$-rational points

Comment: The curve $\overline{C}$ has exactly two singular points, and each of these points has one place over it defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. So the $K$-rational points of $\overline{C}$ are in bijection with $E_C(K)$ under $\phi$.

Comment: Sorry, in my last comment I meant the $K$-rational points of $\overline{C}$ minus the two singular points $(0,0)$ and $(-1,-1)$.

Comment: Is  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ a typo?  Does "each singular has a place over it" mean that  the curve is nonsingular over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for some prime p? Thank you!

Comment: @monoid911 If you prefer, the places over a singular point $p \in \overline{C}$ are the points of the normalisation of $\overline{C}$ which lie above $p$. Here each singular point $p$ is a node, with the two tangents being defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ (easy to see at $(0,0)$: the lowest terms of the equation are $x^2+xy+y^2$), so in the normalisation there are two conjugate points above $p$, each defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. You can think of the normalisation as obtained by separating the tangents.